# Apache unresponsive on OS X Mountain Lion after upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mac

I'm having trouble getting Apache set up on my MacBook in Mountain Lion after I upgraded from Leopard.  I tried following [these instructions](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion).  I have the `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` line uncommented in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, I have a `my_user_name.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/users` with the contents:

```
<Directory "/Users/sarah/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have an index.html file in `/Users/my_user_name/Sites`, chmodded to 644, owned by `my_user_name`.

- However, when I go to `http://localhost/~my_user_name`, I still get 403 Forbidden.
- I created `/Library/WebServer/Documents/phpinfo.php` with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, and when I view that in the browser, I just see the source code.
- When I go to `http://localhost`, I see "It works!".  However, after I do `sudo apachectl stop`, if I visit `http://localhost`, I still see "It works!"--shouldn't that be inaccessible if I've stopped Apache?

It almost seems like there's some other web server behind my `localhost`, and that's why my changes to `httpd.conf` and `my_user_name.conf` aren't making any difference.  Any ideas?

Comment: @SarahVessels Do you perhaps have your install of Apache conflicting with the OS X default install? Check under the sharing control panel that "Web Sharing" is unchecked.

Comment: It sounds like you may have more than one Apache running -- When you stop Apache do you still see any `httpd` processes running in Activity Monitor (or `ps auxw`)?

Comment: @Jeff:  'Web Sharing' is no longer in the system settings under Mountain Lion.

Comment: @voretaq7:  bam, that looks like the problem.  Did `sudo apachectl stop` then `ps auwx | grep httpd` and got several entries like `_www            3157   0.0  0.0  2436152   1776   ??  S    Thu07PM   0:00.03 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`.  So now the question:  how did I get two Apaches, and what should I do to get rid of one?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so we've established you're running multiple `apache` servers.

The first thing I would suggest doing is rebooting -- This is not normally a solution I recommend, but if your system is in some kind of inconsistent state with a half-dead Apache this will resolve it and get you back to a state where the normal tools will work for starting/stopping the web server.

If that fails to get you to a working state you'll have to determine where the extra httpd is coming from (you can use `lsof` (as root) to determine which `httpd.conf` file it's reading, which may contain some clues about what installed it, and how you can go about disabling or reconfiguring it)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the additional webserver is the one that comes built into OS X. It's still there in Mountain Lion, but the UI to enable and disable it has been removed. You can still manage it from the command line, however. OS X starts and maintains the builtin web server with launchd, so you use `launchctl` to manage it. First, check to see if launchd is running apache:

```
$ sudo launchctl list | grep apache
1526    -   org.apache.httpd
```

That result tells me that launchd has started an item with the label org.apache.httpd, and it's running as process ID 1526. If it didn't have an active apache item, the results would be blank.

If it's the system-supplied launchd item, you can turn it off with:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Note that the `-w` makes the unload permanent (without it, the item would be reloaded at the next reboot).

Comment: +1 for -w option for giving a permenant solution.